# Perl, how to print evaluation of sum of numbers using "print"

Tags: perl

Look at the following code sample.

```
$ct=5;
print "hey $ct+1";
```

When evaluated, this returns:

```
hey 5+1
```

However, I'm trying to get the code to return:

```
hey 6
```

Does anybody know if there is some sort of evaluation call that I can make to have this occur correctly, or a way to change the syntax a tad?  I know I could simply do:

```
$dum=$ct+1;
print "hey $dum";
```

But what I'm showing you is a simple version of something more complicated.  If I could get this small example to work correctly, my larger problem is solved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You want to execute a Perl addition operator, but the code only features a Perl string literal. You want

```
print "hey ", $ct+1;
```

If you did have Perl source code in a variable and you wanted to execute it, you'd have to invoke the Perl parser and compiler: [`eval EXPR`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html).

Comment: This assumes that the value of `$,` is undef or the empty string.

Comment: My point is to indicate that it's possible for `$,` to have a different value, in which case this answer is not equivalent to `$dum=$ct+1; print "hey, $dum"`. That's all.

Comment: @chepner, There's no such assumption. I didn't set `$,`, and it defaults to `undef`, so it's undef. You could just as easily have said "that assumes `print` wasn't replaced with another op by an op checker". It's true, but irrelevant. Someone setting `$,` knows what setting `$,` does.

Answer (score 8):

Another alternative is formatted printing.

```
my $ct = 5;
printf "hey %s", $ct+1;
```

Comment: hum, `%d` implies a `int` which wasn't requested and isn't necessary. I would simply use `%s`. This ain't C.

Comment: I just assumed decimal, but yes you are correct that %s would be a well-rounded response.  I'll update it.

Answer (score 2):

This is kind of intermediate Perl, but you can put your expression into a reference and dereference it inside double quotes:

```
print "hey @{[$ct+1]}";
print "hey ${\($ct+1)}";
```

Code like this is harder to read and gives Perl the reputation of being unfriendly to newbies, so I don't recommend it over extracting the expressions out of the quotes:

```
print "hey ", ($ct+1);
print "hey " . ($ct+1);
```

Comment: I'd say that ref-deref pair looks terrible... if I didn't use it myself frequently. :)